# I want to get only the top number from a SQL statement without limiting the other columns

Tags: sql

Putting a report together using 4 tables (A, D,F and T) but having issue with the report taking all numbers in a column when only the top 1 is needed.

All data in report is accurate so my joins are good but the F table is giving more data then is needed... I have tried `Having`, `Max`, `top 1` and a few others without success

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), a.begin_date_of_service, 101) AS Budget_date, 
     t.account_value, 
     a.procedure_code, 
     (t.amount) AS Budget_Track, 
     a.units_authorized, 
     f.amount, 
     d.total_estimated_liab, 
     a.claimed_units, 
     (a.claimed_units * f.amount) AS Paidout, 
     (d.rem_liab_total) AS remainingLiab, 
     ((t.amount) - (a.estimated_liability_code)) AS REMAINING, 
     CASE 
        WHEN d.patid IS NULL THEN f.provid 
        ELSE d.patid 
     END AS IdentifyMember
```

`F.AMOUNT` column has 2 numbers 90 and 80. 80 is the most recent or at the top.

I can't find a way to remove 90 without interfering with remaining report

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your join on the F table by selecting via a temporary virtual table with the WITH command (in Oracle DB).

Example:
`WITH TEMP_TABLE_F as (select * from f where column1 = 0)
select [same as your previous select statement] from A, D, TEMP_TABLE_F, T;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
JOIN F ON column = column
```

Try this instead:

```
JOIN (SELECT * FROM F WHERE AMOUNT = 90) F ON column = column
```

This is pretty common syntax and should work in most DBs.